# How to select or remove everything outside of : :

Tags: windows, notepad++, regex

I need some help with notepad++ and RegEx. I looked for some answers already, but didn't find or understood them. I basically have lines that goes like..

user:$2y$10$Bst0pYRdnpe9kBWTYj925u.VL3ZDuS3lUjxz9SvL/d5UDh6V2A9y:example@mail.com

And I wish to extract the one in the middle section between the : :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I wish to extract the text in the middle section between the `:`s

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*?:)(.*?)(:.*)`
- Set "Replace with" to `\2`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
user:blahblah:example@mail
user:fkdlsfklkdslgkfds:example@mail
user:popbovpxobpfdgfd:example@mail
user:jdspkfokglkf';lkbv';z:example@mail
user:flkdslafeklfkldskf'l:example@mail
user:ddsalfkdlskfl;'dsk:example@mail
```

**After**:

```
blahblah
fkdlsfklkdslgkfds
popbovpxobpfdgfd
jdspkfokglkf';lkbv';z
flkdslafeklfkldskf'l
ddsalfkdlskfl;'dsk
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you for the help sir. I'll continue reading further about it and make some small tests. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to do it in a single pass try

- begin search pattern `^[^:]*:` empty replace
- end line search pattern `:.*$` empty replace

note that while theorically Posix

search pattern will not work `^[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*$` by `\1`

as per Maté's suggestion, this work for me (notepadd++ 6.2.2), tested on OP's sample.

search pattern will not work `^[^:]*:([^:]*):.*$` by `\1`

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, basically I have lots of these lines

user:$2y$10$Bst0pYRdnpe9kBWTYj925u.VL3ZDuS3lUjxz9SvL/d5UDh6V2A9y:example@mail.com.com

Comment: Your second attempt is also close, just need to remove \ characters, you shouldn't escape brackets here.

Comment: It works, but only give me one results and skip all other lines. Not sure why, but almost there :)